# Pandas add column if exists in index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have several csv files which they differ between them in term of columns.

I know exactly which column I want to see, but I am not sure if all the files they have those column.

in my previous code, I had in place this sort of filtering

```
keep_col = ['code', '@timestamp', 'message', 'name','ID', 'deviceAction']
```

know I implemented a for loop to go through all the files (csv) in a folder and run some scripts against those file.

Here is where I am facing the issue.

as the csv structure may vary, I can't keep the `keep_col` that static and I needed to add some extra column,
like this:

```
keep_col = ['code', '@timestamp', 'message', 'name','ad.loginName','sourceServiceName','ad.destinationHosts','ID', 'deviceAction']
```

but unfortunately my script fails because the the new column I added, are not in the csv index. fair enough, I decided to put in place a ìf `statment`

as follow:

```
if 'ad.loginName' and 'sourceServiceName' and 'ad.destinationHosts' in f.index.values:
            keep_col = ['Code', '@timestamp', 'message', 'name','ad.loginName','sourceServiceName','ad.destinationHosts','ID', 'deviceAction']
        else:
            keep_col = ['Code', '@timestamp', 'message', 'name','ID', 'deviceAction']
```

I tried with both `AND` and `OR`and the output was wrong in both cases, and here why:

OR: fails to run because is needs to validate at least one condition, which in my first file does not have any of those column.

AND: works, but does not report back the column because not all 3 conditions are true so it doesn't report back any of those 3 fields.

Please, can any of you help me to solve this.

I would like the script to check IF any of those columns exists, to write them, and if they do not exists in the index, to just ignore them and move on

thank you very much guys, and please if you need more infos just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to check if all indexes you mention are in f.index.value.

```
if all(col in f.columns
       for col in ['ad.loginName', 'sourceServiceName',
                'ad.destinationHosts']
       ):
```

or in other words if that set is a subset of f.index.values

```
if set(['ad.loginName', 'sourceServiceName',
        'ad.destinationHosts']) <= set(f.columns):
```

Or back to your original problem you want

```
keep_col = ['Code', '@timestamp', 'message', 'name','ad.loginName','sourceServiceName','ad.destinationHosts','ID', 'deviceAction']

keep_col = [col for col in keep_col if col in f.columns]
```

If I tell you `'some string' and 'some other string' == True`, can you spot what you did wrong in your code?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. I see your code and I fully understand the process of it and what is supposed to do. but I am confused about the output. the first 2 suggestions, didn't write the new cols to the new file.the first 2 cases, they write only the `else` condition even if the new columns exists in the index. the third example, returns just an empty file. the first two cases are the one confusing me. why the code is jumping to the else directly even if the fields exists?

Comment: @NaydenVan is `f.index.values` what you think it is or did you meant it to be `f.columns`?

Comment: I've adjusted the code and removed the filter. It doesn't produce a list anymore in python3. (Also I still had an `idx` in the third example which I forgot to rename to `col`)